# The best approach to keep API views and Template views in Django

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, directory

I'm looking for the best approach/practice to keep API views and Template views in Django. Making a separate app called `API/` or keeping all views together in the `views.py` file? There is also another approach that creates a directory within the main app called `views/` which includes `views/api.py` and `views/visual.py` and simply removes the traditional `views.py`. Which is better??

Answer (score 2):

Follow the way I have seen many other projects structured as same as the one we use in our company.

```
your_app/
├── __init__.py
├── api/
│ ├── __init__.py
│ ├── serializers.py
│ └── viewsets.py
├── apps.py
├── migrations/
├── templates/
├── admin.py
├── models.py
├── tests.py
├── views.py
```

There is no point you add `viewsets` and `serializers` outside of the same app. It will only confuse your team. Nevertheless, if you are creating `Mixins` and helper functions that may be used across other apps that is the best way living it in a core app for example.

The best way for your understand the best practices is looking at the [django repository](https://github.com/django/django) on github and seeing how they structure their folders. Also, have a read on the book `Two scoops of Django` there the author explains better how to better structure a django project.

The last but not least, my tough is that if those functions belongs strictly to that app leave them where they belong. Modularity will make it easy to fix future problems and even make it easy if one day that app may become a package.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the project.

If the API is going to be a big part then an app makes sense.

Personally I like the views directory, as you can separate views in to subsections if the project requires that.

Comment: What if I implement both API views and Template views equally? Like for each Template view, I create an API view as well.